# How do I limit user options into a database query to the ones from a list?

Tags: ms-access, report, criteria

I have a query with [Which County?] as its Criteria.  So it's already asking the user for the county it's to filter its results by.

I would like the input box that the user types the county name into to be a list box or combo box.  Otherwise, I see a lot of typos being a regular annoyance.

Comment: Replace `[Which Count?]` with listbox or combo box name

Comment: Parameter references combobox or listbox on form: `Forms!formname!comboboxname`. Instead of dynamic parameter in query, my preference is to apply filter to form or report with VBA. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list box whose control source is a table that only contains the options you want the user to select from. There should be a table relationship between the table with the available country options and the table with the field you are filling in the form.